# How to connect Radiobutton to a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to create sample applications, like examination system. I don't know how to connect radio button and textbox to create multiple choices in this system. So can anyone can tell me how to connect radiobutton and textbox to create multiple choices?

Comment: `can anyone can tell me how to ...` SO is for asking (good) questions, not providing tutorials.  You need to spend your own time doing research then post a specific programming question.  See [Ask], read the [FAQ] and take the [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly:

Radio buttons have 'text' property, you can put your description there.

Next, this code should place this Text description in TextBox after clicking this particular RadioButton:

```
Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton.CheckedChanged
      TextBox.ext = RadioButton.text
   End Sub
```

If not, you can always look for answer here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_radio_button.htm